# Calculate totals based on column values

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
 AWBNO               STATUS
 123                DELIVERED
 125                DELIVERED
 124                   RTO
 126                   RTO
 127                   NDR
 128                   NDR
 131                DELIVERED
 132                DELIVERED
 133                   NDR
 134                DELIVERED
```

I want output in this way:-

```
TOTAL       DELIVERED     RTO     NDR
10              5          2       3
```

Comment: ...Come on man, be a bit more descriptive. Add your code and some details.

Answer (score 3):

You can do conditional aggregations based on status like this:

```
select 
    count(*) total,
    count(case when status = 'DELIVERED' then 1 end) DELIVERED,
    count(case when status = 'RTO' then 1 end) RTO,
    count(case when status = 'NDR' then 1 end) NDR
from your_table;
```